# ROWCOUNT in T-SQL is being interrupted by IF statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following T-SQL **pseudo-code** query

```
SET @Loop = 1
WHILE @Loop > 0
BEGIN
 IF (@Table_name = 'abcdef')
    BEGIN 
       SET @SqlCmd = 'update top 1000 @Table_name
                      set columnA = ''haha'''
    END
 ELSE
    BEGIN
       SET @SqlCmd = 'update top 1000 @Table_name  
                      set columnA = ''hehe'''
    END

 EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @SqlCmd
 SET @Loop = @@RowCount
END
```

Now, assume the both @Table_name (abcdef and the other one) has 5000 records,  the update statement inside the "ELSE" clause would just run 5 times and get out of the loop. But, the update statement inside the "IF" clause is falling into an infinite loop. I believe the cause is @@RowCount being interrupted by the IF (@Table_name = 'abcdef'). because @@RowCount always return 1 when running inside that block.

I have a quick (but really ugly) solution for this as follow:

```
SET @Loop = 1
WHILE @Loop > 0
IF (@Table_name = 'abcdef')
   BEGIN 
     SET @SqlCmd = 'update top 1000 @Table_name
                    set columnA = ''haha'''

     SELECT @Loop = COUNT(1) FROM @Table_name WHERE columnA != 'haha'
   END
ELSE
   BEGIN
     SET @SqlCmd = 'update top 1000 @Table_name  
                    set columnA = ''hehe'''
     SET @Loop = @@RowCount
   END

 EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @SqlCmd
END
```

Although the above solution would work, is there a better way to solve the problem? Eager to learn more, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem isn't `@@ROWCOUNT`.  It is:

```
update top 1000 @Table_name
     set columnA = 'haha';
```

If you run this in a loop, it is going to set the same rows over and over.  Perhaps you should use:

```
update top 1000 @Table_name
     set columnA = 'haha'
     where columnA <> 'haha';
```

Comment: Duh, you are right, didn't think about to consolidate ( where columnA <> 'haha';) into my sql. I mean, take that the real query is actually a lot more complicated that this example, but the idea should be the same.. I guess I am being clouded by the part that I thought was wrong.. thanks